# Toggle colors on multiple buttons

Tags: css, angular

How can I toggle background color on multiple buttons.( reference images )

I have set of buttons. Once user click on any button it change the background color and if click again on same button other button the first clicked button reset to original color and change the 2nd click button.

**code**

```
<span class="input-group-btn">

                    <button
                      class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2"
                      (click)="selectToday('approved')"
                    >
                      Select Today
                    </button>
                    <button
                      class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2"
                      (click)="selectWeek('approved')"
                    >
                      To Current Week
                    </button>
                    <button
                      class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2"
                      (click)="selectMonth('approved')"
                    >
                      To Current Month
                    </button>
                    <button
                      class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2"
                      (click)="AllTime('approved')"
                    >
                      All Time
                    </button>
                  </span>
```

Can anyone give me clue how to bind the class with each other

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFZ8T.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use radio button and customize it's display style instead of using Button directly. I am sure i will solve your problem. Just refer to this link:

[Convert Radio button to Button](https://markheath.net/post/customize-radio-button-css)

Answer (score 1):

You can make it dynamic like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sgjppj?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

TS:

```
selected = null

buttons = ["Selecct Today", "Current Week", "Current Week", "All Time"];
```

Template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let btn of buttons;let i=index">
    <button [style.background-color]="selected == i ? 'green' : 'red'" (click)=" selected == i? selected = null:selected = i">
       {{btn}}
    </button>
</ng-container>
```

To change the color of next button on deselection of already selected btn, try this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let btn of buttons;let i=index">
    <button [style.background-color]="selected == i ? 'green' : 'red'" (click)=" selected == i? selected = i + 1:selected = i">
    {{btn}}
  </button>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I updated my question, I already using onclick event, can you give me JSFiddle

Comment: Can u see link I shared? It's stackbiltz

Comment: As per your edited question, try like this,  replace selected = null to selected = i+ 1.  You will have to add a additional condition to check if if I+1 exists. I am not with my laptop now, so can't share the demo

Comment: @FaisalJanjua Have you checked the modified answer?

Answer (score 0):

Give an index or id to each button and give the index on click

```
(click)="enableDisableRule(2)"
```

in your ts, save the index:

```
enableDisableRule(selectedIndex:number){
   ...
   if(this.selectedIndex = selectedIndex){
      this.selectedIndex = null;
   } else{
      this.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
   }
}
```

And in your html, update you button acording to selectedIndex:

```
[style.background-color]="selectedIndex === 2 ? 'green' : 'red'"
```

Or something in this spirit.